# Can i cycle through the different text copied using the Ctrl+c shortcut key

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery, notepad

I typed around 30-40 lines of something very important and in a hurry the notepad wasn't saved and closed.So as the notepad is closed and not saved how can i get back the data which i had entered.

-I had copied the text before closing the notepad but some other text is getting displayed when doing the "Ctrl+V".(so is there any way possible that i can cycle through different text copied using the "Ctrl+C" shortcut key)

**Note**:-To make it clear the notepad is not saved if a saved notepad got deleted then we could retrieve it through software but not getting how to retrieve this.

Comment: Windows does not hold multiple things in the clipboard.  So there is nothing to cycle through.

Comment: ok if windows did not store anything then how are we able to do the Undo then.I am sure it has a limit of storing but don't know where and how

Comment: An undo feature is handled by the individual program not Windows.  A program can also NOT implement clipboard functionality if it wants.  Its even possible for a program to clear the clipboard when its first started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible, the clipboard erases itself when filled again. 
What you have in it may comes from another Copy/Cut/Paste that happened after you closed your notepad window.

- on some OSes the Copy/Paste process may differ from a software from another : Ctrl+C is replaced by Shift+Delete in console commands, or by "overline + right click". This allows you - if I recall right - to have multiple clipboards.

Anyway I regret to say that your unsaved work seems lost to me.

Comment: This is why I use a clipboard manager. You can save your clipboard history and selectively choose or change an entry later on.

Answer (score 1):

Ramhound is correct, Windows does not support this feature by its own.
If you still want this functionality you could go for one of these clipboard managers  listed on this website:
http://lifehacker.com/5298615/five-best-clipboard-managers

Unfortunately it doesn't know the history of the things you copied before you installed any of these applications.

**EDIT (after Ramhounds comment #2) :**
Indeed, a program could decide to not use the clipboard, but the link above describes programs that manages the clipboard for you.
I am using [ArsClip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/cms/showpage.php?cid=97) right now and it tracks a full history of all the different strings (even files and images) you copy.

Just select whatever you want to copy, press `Ctrl+C` and the item is put in the history (and the normal clipboard of Windows). If you want to paste the last copied item, you do as you normally would: press `Ctrl+V`.

If you want to paste anything you've copied earlier, press `Ctrl+Shift+Z` to bring up a simple menu where you can access the complete history. Select the item you want to paste, and you're done.

Comment: both are accepted answers but the above one clarifies the multiple clipboards

Comment: In some sense it acts as a key logger except it also tracks your image clippings as well.It is good that it will track the clip board but will it pose any security issues as it will keep tracking(it may also track/store my card details)

Comment: You can flush the history of ArsClip anytime you want, or even better: just exit ArsClip or any other manager you're using when you are at a page where you copy/paste card details or passwords. But copy/pasting this kind of information is your own security risk, àny program that has access to your clipboard (Word, Wordpad, just about every program with copy/paste functions) is a possible threat when you think like that, @user285oo6